# GCP Node.js execute app in separate subfolder

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I have a node.js app, i want to execute it in: mydomain.com/myapp, because i have a different web in mydomain.com. in a compute engine instance.

How can I run node.js in a subfolder without damage anything in my main domain?

I've tried in cloud shell, and it's okay. I found in the documentation that the next step I have to do is run:

```
gcloud app deploy
```

But I understand that this will make it run on the entire domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have an HTTPS Load Balancer in the front and route traffic based on paths to the internal resource. For example, '/' (root domain) to the Compute Engine VM and '/something' (some path) to an App Engine service. This could help achieve your use case. I'll add some documents which could help.

- [Set up a global external HTTP(S) load balancer with VM instance group backends](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setup-global-ext-https-compute)
- [Set up a global external HTTP(S) load balancer with Cloud Run, App Engine, or Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setup-global-ext-https-serverless)
- [Use URL Maps to route traffic to different backends](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map)